# Сколько стоит хостинг для БД и бэкенда?

Tags: docker, развертывание, hosting, jvm, devops

Делаем дипломную работу в этом полугодии. Сервис на Java Spring и андройд приложение в качестве UI. Возможно, будет ещё фронт на React.

Чтобы было удобно вести разработку, хотим выложить бэк+БД (postgres) на сервер. Плюс это было бы хорошим опытом.

Вопрос в том, сколько это будет стоить, если это делается для учебных целей и насколько сложен процесс деплоя проекта на сервер.

В планах освоить основы докера и сделать докер-контейнеры на каком-нибудь линукс сервере для бэка, базы и, возможно, фронта.

Хотелось бы в ответах увидеть рекомендации, как нам поступить, какой хостинг выбрать, какие методологии использовать.

Хостинг нужен примерно на полгода.

Comment: я для таких целей создаю вируталку в Яндекс Облаке. Плюс облачных решений в том, что можно взять столько ресурсов, сколько нужно и платить только за полученнеые ресурсы

Comment: Самая минимальная виртуалка 400 рублей :/ как вариант, но дороговато получается